# Can I have my screenshot files written immediately in Mojave?

Tags: finder, mojave, screen-capture

In macOS Mojave, whenever you take a screenshot a small preview thumbnail will appear at the bottom-right of your screen, and then it will go away on its own.

I have noticed that the .PNG screenshot file will be written to your Desktop after the thumbnail flies away, rather than instantaneously like it used to be.

This may sound ridiculous but as a very extensive user of the screenshot features, this lag is rather annoying.

The closest solution I have found is that if you manually swipe the thumbnail to the right, your screenshot will be written a bit earlier.

Is it possible to configure the screenshots behavior to write the file immediately? I don't mind deactivating the thumbnail preview - I just want to have the file sitting on my Desktop as soon as possible.

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take screenshots instantly by turning off the thumbnail preview.

This can be achieved by opening the screenshot utility and uncheck the "Show Floating Thumbnail" button.

[image]

*(3rd last option from below)*

The options also allow you to set a timer for taking screenshots.

Comment: You can access the screenshot utility from either: `Applications/Utilities/Screenshot.app` or `CMD` + `Shift` + `5`

Comment: @EliottRobson It's also in LaunchPad, in the folder 'Other'.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I have my screenshot files written immediately in Mojave?

Yes.

Simply use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to open new screenshot utility. Now under Options, uncheck **Show Floating Thumbnail** item.

[image]

You can also customize the default location for saving the screenshot or can choose to copy it directly to clipboard.